# Spring.Net without App.config

Tags: spring.net

I want to configure the spring.net in some other setting files like xml not through app.config.
Is it possible to configure the spring.net in xml not in app.config file.if yes how can i do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can place your configuration in normal xml files. In the Spring.NET documentation, [the following example is given](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-instantiation):

`services.xml`:

```xml
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"> 

  <object id="PetStore" type="PetStore.Services.PetStoreService, PetStore">
    <property name="AccountDao" ref="AccountDao"/>
    <property name="ItemDao" ref="ItemDao"/>
    <!-- additional collaborators and configuration for this object go here -->
  </object>

  <!-- more object definitions for services go here -->

</objects>
```

The file `daos.xml` has a similar structure and contains definitions for `ItemDao` and `AccountDao`.

In code, you can create an instance of your container using the files `services.xml` and `daos.xml` as follows:

```cs
IApplicationContext context = new XmlApplicationContext("services.xml", "daos.xml")
```